# Can't chat with Google Assistant while recording screen

Tags: google-assistant, video-recording

I wanted to record some of my conversations with Google Assistant, and I used the AZ Screen Recorder app to record. However, when I start recording and open up Google Assistant, it gives me the "Can't reach Google at the moment" error, although my internet's working fine.

Also tried with the Mobizen app and some other apps, same connectivity error. When I'm not recording the screen, the Assistant works as normal.

Has anybody else experienced this and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This is because AZ Screen Recorder is using your microphone and Google Assistant uses your microphone to reach your voice.

Go to phone settings, open the app and its permissions, and remove microphone permission from it, and Google Assistant will work perfectly.

The video recorded after that from AZ Screen Recorder will be with no sound (silent video).

Answer (score 0):

Completing the other response:

From architecture perspective, Android restricts the microphone access to only 1 app at a time.

So do not try any other app to make it work, it won't.